# Shifting audio in MPEG4 content and manipulating atoms

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, avconv, mpeg-4, mp4box

### 1. Shift audio

I use **ffmpeg** / **avconv** quite often ... and usually I hate it.
Those tools do what they are instructed to do about 30% of the time. I could give you countless examples but I don't want to start flame war, so please help me with my current problem (really easy one).

I wanted to shift audio (content is standard mp4 file with aac and h264 tracks), so I have found a "highly upvoted" solution:

https://superuser.com/a/983153/758887

the only problem with it is that it doesn't work. I downloaded latest stable ffmpeg (even on windows as in the thread, so it's version was 3.4.1) and executed command without changing literaly anything:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "movie.mp4" -itsoffset 3.84 -i "movie.mp4" -map 0:v -map 1:a -vcodec copy -acodec copy "movie-audio-delayed.mp4"
```

Result was no shift (I expected audio to be 3.84s late).

### 2. Remove MPEG4 atoms

I would be also grateful if you could recommend some tool for removing MPEG4 boxes from content. For examining MPEG4 content I use **MP4 Explorer** / **Codec Visa** (limited) on Windows and **AtomicParsley** on Linux, however they only print atoms and I would like to edit / remove them. For example **MP4Box** can remove whole moov->track with "-rem" option but what if I would like to remove moov->track->edts only?

Comment: How are you testing the output? WMP, for example, doesn't honor late start time of the audio in a MP4.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed I was doing quick checks on WMP and haven't noticed any delays, so I though that it didn't work. In fact ffmpeg adds delay using edts atom (which I also mentioned earlier). Now I've checked different player and it honors delay, so ffmpeg worked ok and it was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

**Shift audio** works ok as pointed out by @Mulvya and I have somehow workarounded **removing MPEG4 atoms**. I've just opened the file with hex editor and changed 'edts' to 'free' ... but if you have better way of doing that the please answer to this question.

Comment: You could try the `-ignore_editlist 1` input option in `ffmpeg`.